# VS 2010 Ultimate web performance test always pending

Tags: visual-studio-2010, load-testing, performance-testing

I've recorded a "web performance test" but when i try to run it, it constantly shows status "pending" and when i try to stop, it just shows message "Test run stopping" and nothing happens. the only way i can stop it is by closing the Visual Studio and reopen it.

the test that i am trying to run is a very simple test of click of a button and capture the response.

i have VS 2010 Ultimate running on Win7 Enterprise.

Comment: Is it possible that you have the current Test Settings configured to use a Controller machine that is unavailable? This can cause the behaviour you describe.  Make sure you have it set to Local Execution.

Comment: I have the same problem for a project that contains just the wizard files generated by VS as a new test project on VS Ultimate Win7 Enterprise

Answer (score 2):

Very similar issue for me.  Fixed it by applying Visual Studio SP1.

Answer (score 1):

Same worked for me.

In my case the installation of VS2012 was the reason for the problem:

- VS2010 was working correctly for months.
- I installed VS2012 Shell
- *Above error showed up.*
- Solved by installing VS2010 ServicePack 1.

Thanks.