# Tests remain in 'pending' state forever

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

In Visual Studio Pro 2010 I cannot run unit tests. They just show a result of "Pending" in the "Test Results" window.

For simplicity I created an empty solution, and added a new C# test project and clicked "Run All Tests in Solution". The "Test Results" window shows, with the default "TestMethod1" test showing, but then nothing happens and the status says "Test run in progress" forever. From there, clicking the stop button changes the status to "Test run stopping..." forever.

After poking around a bit, I found in process explorer that devenv launches QtAgent32 - but neither uses any CPU.

This is the first time I've tried to run unit tests in Visual Studio. Is there a necessary setup step I need to perform to run tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install Service Pack 1 for the fix.

I eventually found a duplicate also providing the answer here: [VS 2010 Ultimate web performance test always pending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659741/vs-2010-ultimate-web-performance-test-always-pending)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little bit to late. I got the same problem and in my case it was the controller full disk the created the truble